# php zip archive

Tags: php, zip, archive

I tried to create empty/not empty zip archive.
Code used is below.

Result: nothing happened.
No errors, but also no results.

Any explanation appreciated.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('/home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/xxx_zip.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
$zip->addFile('/home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/xxxxxx.css');
#$zip->addEmptyDir('.'); //also tried
$zip->close();
```

> available
>   Zip     enabled
>   Extension Version   $Id: php_zip.c,v 1.1.2.50 2009/03/01 17:35:25 iliaa Exp $
>   Zip version     1.8.11
>   Libzip version  0.9.0

Comment: You've checked you have permission to write there?  What are those functions returning?

Comment: if ($zip->open($filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
} see if the open fails

Comment: I feel silly. These were permissions. Should have suspected it first hand. Thank you Orbling for hint. And all of you guys for taking time to read it. Cheers. Jeff

Answer (score 1):

The ZipArchive methods indicate failure by returning false. Did you check that? Did you check [getStatusString](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-getstatusstring.php)?

Answer (score 0):

check out other examples but this is how I got it working:

```
    <?php

        $dirArray = array();

        /* creates a compressed zip file */
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        if ($zip->open('dataminefiles.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
            die ("Could not open archive"); 
        }
        // open the current dir
        if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
            // ignore hidden files          
            if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            // only zip specific files
                if ( substr($entry,-3,3) == "jpg" || substr($entry,-3,3) == "pdf" || substr($entry,-3,3) == "lsx" || substr($entry,-3,3) == "xls" || substr($entry,-3,3) == "doc" || substr($entry,-3,3) == "txt" || substr($entry,-3,3) == "png" || substr($entry,-3,3) == "gif" || substr($entry,-3,3) == "peg" ) {
                    // if allowed, add them to the array
                    $dirArray[] = $entry;
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }

        $indexCount = count($dirArray);
        sort($dirArray);
            // loop through the files and add them to the zip file
        for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
                $file = "{$dirArray[$index]}";
                $zip->addFile($file, $file);
        }
    // close the zip file
        $zip->close();

    ?>
```